# Force https, complex implementation

Tags: tls, apache

I have a website running on a dedicated server (single IP) on apache.
**Multiple domains are pointed to the website** . For ex: sub.abc.com, sub.bcdaf.com

I have now purchased a single SSL certificate for one of the domains (sub.abc.com).
Only SSL only works when user accesses https://sub.abc.com

I want to force users to https when they access http.
And by default, when they access sub.abc.com, it should go to https://sub.abc.com . 
How can i do this via htaccess?

**Please note that the https only works for sub.abc.com and should forcing users should happen only for sub.abc.com**

Comment: This was cross-posted on http://serverfault.com/questions/543991/force-https-complex-implementation/543992?noredirect=1. David, please refrain from cross-posting, it is not appreciated on this network. Also this question has little to do with security... you should learn to read documentation.

Answer (score 1):

redirect as @Terry mentioned is ok, but will not work if users use bookmarks and you want to make them available also in HTTPS:

- dont forget to use [HSTS-Headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)
- Solution using .htaccess only (untested) [(see apache-wiki)](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS)

  ```
  you can skip the %{HTTP_HOST} - condition if you use a
  <virtualhost> - config for each virtual host 
  and no catchall/regex-servernames

  --- first solution 
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub\.abc\.com
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://sub.abc.com/$1 [r=301,L]

  --- 2nd solution 
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub\.abc\.com
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://sub.abc.com/$1 [r=301,L]
  ```
- Solution using Rewrite-Rule and with working deep links / server-config [(prefered by official docs)](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL):

  ```
  <virtualhost :80>
      ServerName sub.abcd.com
      RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://sub.abcd.com/$1     [R=301,L]

  </virtualhost>

  <virtualhost :443>
       ServerName sub.abcd.com
       Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
  </virtualhost>
  ```

Comment: Good point on the bookmarks issue. I forgot about the `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` directives.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with the `Redirect` directive. This works using both `.htaccess` and in `VirtualHost` configurations in `httpd.conf`.

```
Redirect permanent / https://sub.abc.com
```

Comment: Does this work when users access inner pages directly like sub.abc.com/user/add   ?

Comment: @david I don't have apache handy to test it right now but it should. You can also use a directive such as `Redirect permanent /user/add https://sub.abc.com/user/add` if you only want a redirect in certain pages.

Comment: @david I *think* I made a little mistake so I edited my answer. I'm going from memory though, so you will have to play around with the `Redirect` directive a little.

Comment: I only want this work when users access any page of sub.abc.com and not any other domain

Comment: But the solution above will do a redirect for all domains. Thank you.